# How to Play MID file in Android?

Tags: android, midi

I am writing a small piece of code

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://..../file.mid");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

which is not working, where as

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://..../file.mp3");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this thread on the Pragmatic Forums:
[Java SE5 javax.sound (MIDI) classes removed from Android libraries?](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/138/topics/4103)

Your best option appears to be through the [JetPlayer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/JetPlayer.html)